# Proof for the inverse Fouriertransformation

Tags: fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

I am currently refreshing my knowledge about the fourier series and fourier transformations
and had to figure out, that I never saw how the fourier transformation is derived from the
fourier series. Sadly, I do not even know a book covering this derivation.
Therefor I was reading stuff online and found a pdf from the University of Hamburg,
Germany where the following conjecture is given:

\begin{align}
f(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)e^{i\omega(t-\tau)}d\tau d\omega
\end{align}

This conjecture is then given as a theorem iff $f$ is continuous on every finite intervall and the integral:

\begin{align}
||f||_{L1} := \int_{\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt
\end{align}

exists. Last but not least it is said that if $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ the double
integral gives the mean value of the left and right sided limit.
I would really appreciate if one of you could give me a hint for literature
covering the step Fourier Series -> Fourier Transformation, or give me some advice
on the topic itself.

Thank you very much!

**PS:**
The pdf I refer to can be found at:
https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/teaching/export/tuhh/cm/kf/08/vorl12.pdf
Sadly it is written in german and contains some mistakes as well

**PPS:**
My current approach is to assume, that:
\begin{align}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega(t-\tau)}d\omega
\end{align}
behaves like a $\delta$-distribution, in the form, that
it is $0$ for $t\neq \tau$ but $\infty$ for $t = \tau$.
If this assumption should turn out to be true the proof would
follow quite easily. Sadly I can not proof this assumption either.

Comment: A couple things. First, why don't you link the pdf from the University of Hamburg so people can see it if they want. Second, what 'conjecture' are you referring to? All you have written down is a double integral for $f(t)$?

Comment: I do not linked the pdf cause it is written in german, but I will add it. The conjecture is, that the following formula is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I came up with an answer:

In the **PPS** of the question one can read, that my approach is to show,
that
\begin{align}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega(t-\tau)}dt
\end{align}
somewhat `behaves` like a delta distribution. I now know, that this
expression is rather sloppy. Furthermore the integral from $]-\infty, \infty[$ is not defined. So lets introduce:

\begin{align}
f_v(x) = \int_{v}^{v}e^{-i\omega x}dx\quad, where\ x = t-\tau
\end{align}
We can now work with distributions of $f_v$:

\begin{align}
T_v[\phi] &:= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f_v(x)\phi(x)dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-v}^{v}dw\,e^{-i\omega x}\phi(x)\\
\end{align}

Considering the limit we get:

\begin{align}
\lim_{v\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-v}^{v}dw\,e^{-i\omega x}\phi(x) &= \lim_{v\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\phi(x)\int_{-v}^{v}dw\,e^{-i\omega x}\\
&= \lim_{v\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\phi(x)\left[\frac{-1}{ix}(e^{-ivx} - e^{ivx})\right]\\
&= \lim_{v\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\phi(x)\frac{sin(vx)}{\pi x}
\end{align}

It is known, that the last statement converges (as a distribution)
to the delta-distribution. This has to be the case as
the function $f(x) = \frac{sin(vx)}{\pi x}$ is Lebesgue integrable
and integrated over $[-\infty, \infty]$ the integral is $1$.